# Is there a way to lock a node?

Tags: node-editor

Is there a way to lock a node within a single .blend file so that it can't be adjusted by accident? I've searched the site and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: It's possible to link nodetree from another file and nodes won't be editable. As another option you can hide unused sockets with Ctrl+H but the input sockets must be unused for that to work. Other than that groups might be more flexible solution

Answer (score 2):

you could just hide the node? (press H) Then it would look like this:
[image: Hidden/collapsed node]

if you have multiple nodes, i suggest you make a [node group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/compositing/types/groups.html), which will protect the nodes inside the group

I don't think there is a lock functionality